# Two Ethernet Network connection icons in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, taskbar

Is there a reason why I have two Ethernet Network Connection 'Wired Connection 1' active icons on the panel in Lubuntu 14.04? This appeared a few weeks ago, and I tried to delete one of them, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue after an update. I believe the update may have fixed the bug that required nm-applet to be manually added to the autostart list. I removed my addition to the startup list, then logged out and back in and the extra panel icon was gone. (My automatic updates seem to have been fixed as well).

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `/etc/xdg/autostart`.  If you have more than one `nm-applet-*.desktop`, just delete/move unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
sudo kill -9 nm-applet
```

then

```
sudo nm-applet
```

Comment: nm-applet doesn't need root permissions - you should not start it with `sudo`.